# JavaScript alert with escaped characters fail

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, escaping, alert

Why does the following JavaScript fail, when you click on the link? And is there any way to fix it?

```
<a onclick="alert('Do you want to delete &lt; &gt; &quot; &#39;?');">Link</a>
```

I am aware that the escaped characters would be illegal if they were printed literally, but I can't see why it should fail when then are escaped. Leaving out the characters is not an option, as it is user defined.

Comment: An alert message is not html, it depends on the system. You don't need to escape entities, just characters that you'd regularly escape inside a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&#39;` is considered a single quote, you need to escape it with a `\`, so `\&#39;`

Without escaping, javascript will throw an "unterminated string literal" error.

This works:

```
<a onclick="alert('Do you want to delete &lt; &gt; &quot; \&#39;?');">Link</a>
```

Comment: Grr, okay. The problem is that the alert text is generated using Spring's <message /> tag. It doesn't work for any combination of values for htmlEscape and javaScriptEscape.

Comment: The string seems to be generated by htmlEscape="true" rather than javaScriptEscape="true".

Comment: Yes. The problem is the order of escaping. If I set htmlEscape to false and javaScriptEscape to true, it generates onclick="alert('Do you want to delete < > \" \'?');" which will also fail, because of the double quotes I assume.